# postfix flush results in 'connect to transport private/[127.0.0.1]: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, postfix

I am running postfix on OpenSuSE LEAP 15.2, and have recently upgraded the OS and software. Postfix is now version 3.4.7 in 'compatibility mode'.

I can seemingly send mail to and from anyone successfully, but I have three messages in the queue that will not go away (probably got there as a result of a transient error). When I run `postfix flush` I get the following in the syslog:

```
Dec 17 03:41:55 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[14088]: BFEC221FCE5: from=<name@local.domain>, size=9391, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 17 03:41:55 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[14088]: warning: connect to transport private/[127.0.0.1]: No such file or directory
```

and it remains in the queue with a status of `mail transport unavailable`. I enabled more verbose messaging for in qmgr and got:

```
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: trigger_server_accept_fifo: trigger arrived
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: master_notify: status 0
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: request: 70 (F)
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: request: 65 (A)
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: request: 68 (D)
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: request: 73 (I)
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_enable_all
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_scan_start: start incoming queue scan
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_enable_all
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_scan_start: start deferred queue scan
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: master_notify: status 1
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_active_feed: queue deferred
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_active_feed: deferred/B/BFEC221FCE5
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_message_alloc: active BFEC221FCE5
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: BFEC221FCE5: recipient limit 5000
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: BFEC221FCE5: from=<name@local.domain>, size=9391, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: start sorted recipient list
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_message_sort: other.name@gmail.com
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: end sorted recipient list
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: start sorted recipient list
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_message_sort: other.name@gmail.com
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: end sorted recipient list
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_transport_select: [127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: qmgr_active_drain: allocate [127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: connect to subsystem private/[127.0.0.1]: No such file or directory
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: warning: connect to transport private/[127.0.0.1]: No such file or directory
Dec 17 03:01:22 my.server.name postfix/qmgr[13028]: done incoming queue scan
```

I'd be interested to know what else I can do to debug this, or just understand what postfix is actually trying to do.

Any help appreciated!

**Edit #1:**

If it helps, the ONLY un-commented-out occurrences of 127.0.0.1 in the settings are:

```
main.cf:inet_interfaces = my.ip.addr,localhost,127.0.0.1
main.cf:content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

(and `postconf -n` shows the same).

**Edit #2:**

I am beginning to think that it may be something intrinsic to the messages that are queued. I deliberately dropped the external interface, sent another message so that it would be delayed, then opened the interface and flushed the queue. It was sent, but the original three remain.

Perhaps...messages retain routing info and that reflects an old misconfiguration?

**Edit #4:**

It looks like it was a message or queue related problem. I stopped postfix (`postfix stop`) then did a "structure check" (`postsuper -s`) and restarted postfix. When I subsequently flushed the queue, all messages were sent.

Weirdness. Would love to know what was actually wrong...perhaps next time!

Comment: Af first glance that seems like you have configured 127.0.0.1 somewhere where that is either not a valid setting or an incorrect format for a hostname

Comment: The only uncommented lines that have 127.0.0.1 in them are:

main.cf:inet_interfaces = my.ip.addr,localhost,127.0.0.1
main.cf:content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

(and postconf -n shows the same).

I have ammended the original question to reflect this.